# Python Plotly: autosize table plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I'm plotting tables of different sizes with Plotly that I want to export as an image. However the size of the plot doesn't automatically scale with the table size resulting in only part of the table displayed in the image (or lot's of white space if I set the plot size too large). I know I can make the height of the layout dependent on the number of rows but this doesn't solve the problem because the space occupied by each row is also dependent on the actual table content (e.g. large strings will require more space).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=df.columns,
                fill = dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),
    cells=dict(values=[df.A, df.B, df.C, df.D],
               fill = dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
               align = ['left'] * 5))
layout = dict(autosize=True)
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig, show_link=False)
```

[example of image export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oay0f.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code produces a blank figure for me. This may be a plotly/Jupyter notebook bug. However, demos from the plotly page plot correctly... This code creates a table for you in Jupyter?

Comment: Yes it does, also in a brand new notebook with nothing else loaded. Plotly version is 2.2.3 and they recently updated a lot, maybe that makes the difference?

Comment: Anyway the following example from Plotly itself illustrates the same point: https://plot.ly/python/table/ (3rd example 'Pandas Dataframe')

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a perfect solution, the arguments will need tweaking depending on font size, number of columns and the lengths of input strings. But it does the job.

```
def calc_table_height(df, base=208, height_per_row=20, char_limit=30, height_padding=16.5):
    '''
    df: The dataframe with only the columns you want to plot
    base: The base height of the table (header without any rows)
    height_per_row: The height that one row requires
    char_limit: If the length of a value crosses this limit, the row's height needs to be expanded to fit the value
    height_padding: Extra height in a row when a length of value exceeds char_limit
    '''
    total_height = 0 + base
    for x in range(df.shape[0]):
        total_height += height_per_row
    for y in range(df.shape[1]):
        if len(str(df.iloc[x][y])) > char_limit:
            total_height += height_padding
    return total_height
```

You might have to play around with the other features if you have a different `font_size` than the default, or if you change the `margin` from the default. Also, the `char_limit` argument of the function is the other weakpoint as some characters take up more space than others, capital characters take up more space, and a single word if long can force a row to be extended. It should also be increased if the number or columns are less and vice versa. The function is written taking 4 table columns (this question) as baseline.

#### Code after defining the function

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=df.columns,
                fill = dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),
    cells=dict(values=[df.A, df.B, df.C, df.D],
               fill = dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
               align = ['left'] * 5))
layout = dict(height=calc_table_height(df))                #This is changed
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig, show_link=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and finally made function that perfectly fit layout to my tables.
The peculiarity of the method is that it prints all data in one row per cell.
But it looks ok for not too long strings.

You can play with `char_width` and other constants. But this values I got experimentally as the best.

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
title = 'My table'

    # set used font width
char_width = 10 
header_char_width = 11

    # Max length of each column
max_len = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).max()
column_widths = [int(max_len[col] * char_width) for col in df.columns]

    # Check if headers longer than data
column_widths = [max(column_widths[i], len(df.columns[i]) * header_char_width, 4*char_width) for i in range(len(df.columns))]

    # Create go.Table
table = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                font=dict(size=14)),
    cells=dict(values=df.values.transpose(),
               height = 25), # default height for each row  
    columnwidth=column_widths
)


    # Calc layout size
l_width = max(sum(column_widths) + 100, len(title)*11) # check if title is longer than table
l_height = 250 + (df.shape[0] * 25) # height based on row count + space for layout

layout = go.Layout(
    height=l_height,
    width=l_width,
    title=title
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[table], layout=layout)

fig.show()
```